# J2ME bouncycastle incompatible types required: Throwable found DataLengthException

Tags: exception, java-me, try-catch, bouncycastle

I have some code with `bouncycastle` that generates an exception, but even if i surround with try catch, the catch statement still give me this error :

```
  incompatible types
  required: java.lang.Throwable
  found:    org.bouncycastle.crypto.DataLengthException
```

here is my code:

```
int decryptedLength;
try {
      decryptedLength = cipher.processBytes(cipherBytes, 0, cipherBytes.length,     decryptedBytes, 0);
    } catch (DataLengthException ex) {
    }
```

the catch statement doesn't accept the exception, how to solve this ?

Comment: did you try `catch (Throwable ex)`? also, avoid having empty catch blocks (search web for something like _Java swallow exceptions_ if you're interested why that would be a **bad idea**)

Comment: even if i add catch (Throwable ex), the error persist. for the catch body, i deleted ex.printStackTrace() because DataLengthException does not have it !

Comment: the error means that DataLengthException doesn't implements Throwable !!

Comment: really? [API documentation](http://www.docjar.org/docs/api/org/bouncycastle/crypto/DataLengthException.html "here") states that DataLengthException extends Throwable

Comment: that's what i see, but i really don't know where's the problem :(
from other topics which have the same problem, they said that the exception doesn't implement Throwable or the version is not compatible !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I changed the project name and there are no more errors. I am using Netbeans (7.3).
I hope this will help someone to avoid losing hours looking for a solution to a problem which doesn't exist.