# HibernateException and Throwable

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm trying to test does hibernate work in my project, for that I'm trying to create session, and IDEA tells me that `org.hibernate.HibernateException` and `java.lang.Throwable` are incompatible and my attempts to cast one to another also failed. Project is desktop app on Java SE 8, has only `hibernate-core-5.2.4.Final` and `hibernate-commons-annotations-5.0.1.Final` libraries connected.
`Main` class:

```
import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

    public class Main {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            try {
                SessionFactory session;
                session = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
                session.openSession();
            } catch (HibernateException e) { //fail
                e = (Throwable)e; //fail
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

There's `hibernate.cfg`:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name=«show_sql»>true</property>
    <property name=«connection.url»>jdbc:sqlite://db/DB.db</property>
    <property name=«connection.driver_class»>org.sqlite.jdbc</property>
    <property name=«connection.username»>root</property>
    <property name=«connection.password»/>
    <property name=«connection.pool_size»>1</property>
    <property name=«current_session_context_class»>thread</property>
    <property name=«dialect»>main.java.SQLiteDialect</property>

<!--> there're some mapping resouces   
    <mapping resource=«logic/File.hbm.xml»/>
<-->    
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

I don't understand reasons of this error, because googling has showed following hierachy:

```
java.lang.Object
└extended by java.lang.Throwable
 └extended by java.lang.Exception
  └extended by java.lang.RuntimeException
   └extended by org.hibernate.HibernateException
```

Maybe Java 8 doesn't support hibernate correctly, or smthng like this?

Comment: please post stack trace of the exception

Comment: I just wonder why do you cast `e = (Throwable)e;`. It always give a compile error.

Comment: If they are not compatible, casting wont change that ...

Comment: There's no stack trace, I can't launch app

Comment: The problem is a misleading error message from Intellij. See my answer below.

Answer (score 4):

I had the exact same problem. It turned out, that I had missed to import javax.persistence (as seems to be your case also).

Just import hibernate-jpa as well. In my case it was hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar.

To import the appropriate hibernate-jpa, you can just use "Configure Module Library" in Intellij and choose "Change Version".

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this, because your variable `e` has a type `HibernateException` when you declare it in `catch` block.

You need to create new variable with `Throwable` type and assign cast `e` variable to it, like this:

```
} catch (HibernateException e) {
    Throwable ex = (Throwable)e;
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

The best way is the [wrapping exception](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-exception-handling/exception-wrapping.html), like this:

```
} catch (HibernateException e) {
    Throwable ex = new Throwable(e);
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Or do something like this:

```
} catch (HibernateException e) {
    try {
        throw (Throwable) e;
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But this method redundant and I think you don't want to use this.

Comment: @ДмитрийПеньков You are welocome!

Answer (score 1):

Aside from being an awful idea, this fails because you're assigning it to itself.

So you have an object of type `HibernateException`, which you cast to `Throwable` (not required, since a cast to a more general type is useless).

Then you're assigning this `Throwable` to a variable of type `HibernateException`. At that point the compiler complains because the thing you're assigning might not be compatible with `HibernateException` (for all he knows at that point, it could also be an `IllegalArgumentException` for example, also a `Throwable`, but not a `HibernateException`).

So you cannot assign that.

If you'd fix that code you'd end up doing
`e = (HibernateException) e;` which is even more insane.

The real question is: What are you really trying to achieve here?

Comment: I've tried to test connection by opening session. IDEA asks for handling exception, I tried with try/catch (I tried not correctly, but this method anyway shows inconvertible types of exceptions), tried to add expression to a method signature, but problem is still alive. I can't understand how to solve that `org.hibernate.HibernateException` and `Throwable` are inconvertible, cause I can't find out the reasons of happening.

Comment: I am not convinced IDEA (I guess its IntelliJ IDEA you are talking) asked for exception handling since `HibernateException` is unchecked exception and compiler doesn't force you to catch or throw them.

Comment: If you just want to ignore the exception, just get rid of that one line and just log the error like you're doing.  But as @Pramod says, `HibernateException` is unchecked so it shouldn't be needed anyway.

Answer (score 1):

This is not related to Hibernate but a general concept in Java.

> ```
> catch (HibernateException e) { //fail
>        e = (Throwable)e; //fail
>        e.printStackTrace();
> }
> ```

The reference e was originally of type `HibernateException` and inside catch block now you are trying to cast it to one of its parent class `Throwable` which is not compatible.

In general you can't assign a parent object to a child reference, if you try to do so it will be `ClassCastException` and If you try to upcast a reference it will be compile time error.

Comment: Yeah, I understand that I missed here. Why `HibernateException` can't be handled correctly? I've imported `org.hibernate.HibernateException`, I can't find out what my code needs.

Comment: What do you mean by can't handled correctly? What I understand from your code is that you are catching `HibernateException` and trying to print the `StackTrace`. You don't need to cast the exception to `Throwable` to print the `StackTrace`. Just have `e.printStackTrace();` statement in the catch block and you are done.

Comment: I've just created method throwing `HibernateException`, IDEA underlines it, and tells: "Incompatible types, required `java.land.Throwable`, found `org.hibernate.HibernateException`" that's thing raising the quetions.

Comment: In this case there is nothing wrong with your code, if you just remove the casting `e = (Throwable)e;`. This is issue with your IDE. Try re-importing the project or if possible renaming as suggested in http://stackoverflow.com/q/10734372/3503187

Comment: Thanks a lot, I think that's my case. I'll do some experiments with project name tomorrow and write results here.

Answer (score 1):

I would just like to add to Vering's answer that if you have Hibernate version which is compatible with jakarta.persistence instead of javax.persistence, then you need to import jakarta.persistence instead of javax.persistence.
First downloading and then importing jakarta.persistence.* was the solution that worked for me. My Hibernate version is 6.0.1. If you have an older version then importing javax.persistence may work for you.
Here is the website from which I downloaded jakarta.persistence
https://jar-download.com/artifacts/jakarta.persistence/jakarta.persistence-api

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Maven and in my case I was simply missing jakarta.persistence dependency.

I added it to `pom.xml`, reloaded the Maven project and it works fine

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```